# Facebook thumbail issues when sharing blogger links

Tags: facebook, image, thumbnails, blogger

I write movie reviews and share them on Facebook. At first the facebook thumbnails would show the pictures I wanted for my reviews, like the movie poster. However, now they only show my blogger profile picture every single time I post a link. It's very frustrating because I want to be taken seriously and I don't want my blogger profile picture showing up every time I post a link. I tried the facebook developers debugging tool and it did nothing. Does anyone have any other suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know to what extent you can modify the HTML code of a Blogger blog, but you can use [Open Graph tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) to define the exact image you want Facebook to show, for example the tag you want is the following:

which must have a 100px x 100px size at least. Note that this tag goes into the Head section of the site.

Answer (score 0):

It has taken some time, but I think I have worked out what is happening, thanks to Facebook Debugger. Put the post URL in and then scroll down to "OPen Graph Warnings That Should be Fixed". You may see something like this -

Provided og:image could not be downloaded or is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook.

Chances are your image is too small and that is why it is grabbing the profile image. I played around with my posts until I got it right, checking it through Debugger each time. It was a pain, but it worked.